# Rails date range JSON data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm looking to have a date range from `1.month.ago..Date.today`, then for each day select the maximum temperature (so should get 30 individual numbers), then sum up the results.

I obtain the data in JSON format which is structured like this

```
{"status": "ok", "data": [{"temperature": 22.4, "date": "20160815-0345"}}
```

I parse the data through a loop.

```
@data['data'].each do |d|
 maxTotal << [DateTime.parse(d['date']), d['temperature']]
end
```

But fall short on how to select the maximum for each day and then sum it up.

```
@total = maxTotal { |a| a[0].to_date == (1.month.ago.to_date) }.max { |a,b| a[1] <=> b[1] }.sum[1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Updated: Tested and Working

```
json_data = @data['data']
sum_of_max_temperature_in_each_day = json_data.
  group_by{ |h| Date.parse(h[:date]) }.
  reject{ |k, v| !( ((30.days.ago.to_date)..(Date.today)) === k ) }.
  inject(0){ |sum, h| sum + h.second.max_by{ |h| h[:temperature] }[:temperature] }
```

#### Explanation (Breaking it down)

```
# Example; let json_data be
json_data = [
  {"temperature": 22.4, "date": "20160815-0345"},
  {"temperature": 10.4, "date": "20160815-1435"},
  {"temperature": 15.8, "date": "20990101-0430"},
  {"temperature": 4, "date": "20160816-0101"}
]

# sum of max temperature each day within last 30 days
puts json_data.
  group_by{ |h| Date.parse(h[:date]) }.
  reject{ |k, v| !( ((30.days.ago.to_date)..(Date.today)) === k ) }.
  inject(0){ |sum, h| sum + h.second.max_by{ |h| h[:temperature] }[:temperature] }
=> 26.4

# 1) Group by day
puts json_data.
  group_by{|h| Date.parse( h[:date] )}
{
  Mon, 15 Aug 2016=>[
    {:temperature=>22.4, :date=>"20160815-0345"},
    {:temperature=>10.4, :date=>"20160815-1435"}
  ],
  Thu, 01 Jan 2099=>[
    {:temperature=>15.8, :date=>"20990101-0430"}
  ],
  Tue, 16 Aug 2016=>[
    {:temperature=>4, :date=>"20160816-0101"}
  ]
}

# 2) Remove those not within the last 30 days
puts json_data.
  group_by{ |h| Date.parse(h[:date]) }.
  reject{ |k, v| !( ((30.days.ago.to_date)..(Date.today)) === k ) }

{
  Mon, 15 Aug 2016=>[
   {:temperature=>22.4, :date=>"20160815-0345"},
   {:temperature=>10.4, :date=>"20160815-1435"}
  ],
  Tue, 16 Aug 2016=>[
    {:temperature=>4, :date=>"20160816-0101"}
  ]
}

# 3) Showing what's happening inside the inject() block.
puts json_data.
  group_by{ |h| Date.parse(h[:date]) }.
  reject{ |k, v| !( ((30.days.ago.to_date)..(Date.today)) === k ) }.
  inject(0){ |sum, h| 
    puts "h ==> #{h}";
    puts "h.second ==> #{h.second}";
    puts "h.second.max_by ==> #{h.second.max_by{ |h| h[:temperature] }[:temperature]}"
  }

h ==> [
  Mon, 15 Aug 2016,
  [
    {:temperature=>22.4, :date=>"20160815-0345"},
    {:temperature=>10.4, :date=>"20160815-1435"}
  ]
]
h.second ==> [
  {:temperature=>22.4, :date=>"20160815-0345"},
  {:temperature=>10.4, :date=>"20160815-1435"}
]
h.second.max_by ==> 22.4
h ==> [
  Tue, 16 Aug 2016, 
  [
    {:temperature=>4, :date=>"20160816-0101"}
  ]
]
h.second ==> [
  {:temperature=>4, :date=>"20160816-0101"}
]
h.second.max_by ==> 4
```

Comment: Thanks Jay, Could you explain the use of second in h.second.max_by? It seem that this is grating the second record of the day, not the max.

Comment: @DollarChills ohh no, the `.second` refers to the second of variable `h` in which `h` is an Array with a size of two as you could see from above. You will notice that `h.first` is the Key, and `h.second` is corresponding Value. This is because inject() loops through each key-value pair in the hash (refer to part 2) hash above), and then `h` becomes something like [key, value] Array instead of a hash {key: value}. That is why again the `h.second` refers to the value pointed by the key (key is a Date, and value is an Array of hashes of :temperature and :date; see above) Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Seems to work just fine. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: @DollarChills no worries. Glad to be of help :)